# Logical strength of the pigeon-hole principle for measure spaces

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, reverse-math

In his book on measure theory, Tao discuss the *pigeon-hole principle for measure spaces*, which expresses that the union of measure zero sets is again measure zero.

I am interested in the logical strength of the following **second-order** special case.  In particular, does PHP imply WKL over RCA$_0$? If not, what about WWKL?

**PHP:** *If $ (X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of measure zero **RM-closed sets** of reals in $[0,1]$, then $ \bigcup_{n \in\mathbb{N} } X_n$ is measure zero.*

Note the boldface to emphasise the RM-coding of closed sets in PHP.  For completeness, a set $C$ of reals has 'measure zero' if for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a sequence of intervals $(I_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\cup_n I_n$ covers $C$ and $\epsilon > \sum_n |I_n|$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the reverse mathematics of the usual pigeonhole principle (for finite sets) look like?

Comment: There are a number of variations, studied e.g. here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/25676784

Comment: You've linked to Gaspar and Kohlenbach, "On Tao's "finitary" infinite pigeonhole principle" [doi link](https://doi.org/10.2178/jsl/1264433926). They do indeed discuss many variations of Tao's pigeonhole principle from a reverse mathematics perspective. Could you explain how your formulation of Tao's pigeonhole principle relates to the ones that they discuss?

Comment: On the other hand, my [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444702/logical-strength-of-the-pigeon-hole-principle-for-measure-spaces?noredirect=1#comment1148277_444702) was much more elementary -- I was not asking about Tao's pigeonhole principle, but rather the _usual_ pigeonhole principle, which says that a map from an m-element set to an n-element set is noninjective if $m > n$ are natural numbers. (Perhaps it's provable in $RCA_0$ and hence uninteresting from a reverse mathematics perspective?)

Comment: @TimCampion The infinite pigeonhole principle is equivalent to (some kind of) induction axiom, called B$\Sigma_2$, which is rather weak even compared to RCA$_0$. The finite version is indeed just provable.

Comment: @TimCampion The pigeonhole principle for measure spaces and the usual pigeonhole principle are not obviously related, as far as I know.